# Using flask to use a function

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to use functions inside of flask, but I don't know how to properly do it.

How do I define the functions,

**Example**

```
def foo(a, b):
    ...
```

Comment: Flask is just python code.. Do you know how to call a function in python?

Comment: Yeah, I am bad at comprehending things right now, Ill edit everything in the morning.

Comment: Gonna have to -1 this one if no update.

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return "<h1>Hello World</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=False)
```

for example index is a function example that will run in the specified address below.

Comment: I already know how to do this, I meant using functions inside of the html